# Issue with using OAuth token in REST API

Tags: rest-api, oauth, oauth2

I implemented the OAuth integration with my external app. Created a Remote Access(Connected App) configuration with a callback url (https://mysite.com/oauthcallback). Here I received the call back with a "code=xyz...". I made a http post with the following params to https:/login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

```
"code":code
"grant_type", "authorization_code"
"client_id", "XYZ..."
"client_secret", "123..."
"redirect_uri", "https:/mysite.com/oauthcallback"
```

for which I received the following response from sfdc

```
"issued_at": "1375365820732",
 "scope": "refresh_token",
 "access_token": "00Dabc..!ABC...",
 "refresh_token": "abc...",
 "signature": "XYZ..."
```

I use the refresh token and fetch the access token or for time being use the access_token I get here for the following REST API
https:/naxx.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Account/accountId
and set the header as 
Authorization: Bearer

This returns me invalid session ID.
Also tried the following options
Authorization: OAuth 
X_SFDC_Session:

The Remote access(Connected App) has the access for "Refresh_Token", "API", Full Access"   :) 
I end up with the same error. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: The specific error that I am receiving is --"message": "This session is not valid for use with the REST API",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"

Comment: post some code.

Answer (score 2):

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm&language=en_US

reading this awesome article from sfdc its very clearly mentioned that " **full does not return a refresh token. You must explicitly request the refresh_token scope to get a refresh token**".

hence a  refresh_token access is also needed .

Comment: Hi @mohith , I did follow these steps and got the refresh token successfully. In the scope I have added refresh token also as I mentioned along with full access and api access. With the refresh token I was able to get the access token too. But when i use it with a rest api it throw invalid session I'd error.

Comment: I'm following the steps similar to what is explained in this link http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API . esp the sections that talks about making a SOQL rest api call, that is where I am getting the error.

Comment: post the code you are using to call api from sfdc?

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, basically the call that I was making for authorize was as following
https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=refresh_token&client_id=&display=popup&redirect_uri=https://mysite.com/oauthcallback

In the above url you can see that I mentioned the scope=refresh_token, this restricted the scope of the authorization and the refresh_token(and subsequently access_token) I receive does not have permission to access the Rest API's

Solution:- Specify scope=refresh_token,api,full access or just remove the parameter, it will pick up the all the scope from remote access (Connected app).

Thanks for your help Mohit!